# What is the aspx/ascx view page equivalent of #include Someplace.Models?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In my Controllers I obviously #include namespaces so I don't have to write out the entire thing when making objects. What is the way to do this inside the aspx/ascx View files? Currently I am having to write out these entire namespaces and it's getting pretty lame.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll want to use the [`Import` directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eb44kack.aspx).

```
<%@ Import Namespace="Someplace.Models" %>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you know if it is possible to consolidate multiple namespace references to one Import tag? Maybe some delimiter after the = or something?